# UIImagePickerController finishing picking when the app goes to background on time when video still compressing

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uiimagepickercontroller, ios-background-mode

We got a problem with `UIImagePickerController`: in our application users can pick media with big size(for example 4k video). For media picking we use UIImagePickerController and everything worked well.

But if the user moves the device to sleep, when selected media on processing, and come to the app again - then delegate method fired.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any])
```

and in info dictionary its consist only two values: `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL` and `UIImagePickerControllerMediaType`.

So it is missing needed values for getting URL of picked assets. Delegate method fired exactly when the app returns from the background and clearly earlier then media should be processed.

Due to files can be very big, we can`t afford user to reselect asset each time that app goes to background. Maybe anyone had this problem and know a solution?

Comment: Implement the time-consuming processing as a background task?

Comment: @matt Unfortunately, we have not much control over `UIImagePickerController`. As I investigated: picker anyway compress selected asset, so this problem could happen at any time. The only option to compress in the background is to make a custom picker or use some pod, which is the radical solution.

Comment: Yes, I was afraid of that...